# Init HalconWindow/HSmartWindowControlWPF in Background in C#

Tags: c#, .net, halcon

Is there any way to initialize a `HalconWindow` or a `HSmartWindowControlWPF` in C#?
I am having multiple `HSmartWindowControlWPFs` in a TabView but only those that were visible before are updated. So if I am trying to put an `HImage` in all `HalconWindows`, without choosing another Tab than the default before, only the default Tab gets updated, all other `HalconWindows` stay black. But if they were once selected they are updated. 
Is there any way to create this behaviour automatically?

Comment: Could you add code sample please?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to index through the tabs at initialization so that they initialize the controls.

```
    private void TabbedHalconApp_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl1.BeginInit();
        for (int index = 0; index < this.TabControl1.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            this.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = index;
            this.TabControl1.UpdateLayout();
        }
        // Reset to first tab
        this.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        TabControl1.EndInit();
    }
```

Then you can load the image to the Halcon window.  Here is how you might do this when the form is loaded.

```
    private void HWindow2_Loaded(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as HSmartWindowControlWPF).HalconWindow.DispImage(myTestImage);
    }

    private void HWindow1_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as HSmartWindowControlWPF).HalconWindow.DispImage(myTestImage);
    }
```